# How to override a css !important property using jQuery with transitions

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking to override the css `!important` property using jQuery. Don't tell me `$('div').css("cssText", "display: none !important;");` I knew it work though I need some kinda transition when it goes of. I just put my hands on to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/8gavv7n2/) where I can make my point more clear.

**jQuery**

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $('div').fadeOut('slow').css("cssText", "display: none !important;");
});
```

Comment: `!important` dosen't work in jquery `.css`

Comment: You can actually override using jquery `$('div').css("cssText", "display: none !important;");` all I need is while make it hide need some kinda transistion

Comment: something like this? http://codepen.io/AmruthPillai/pen/axvqB

Comment: what is `cssText` it is not a valid css property??

Comment: @MrCoder no not like that

Comment: @JakubMichálek..although `.css` puts styles inline but it can't override `!important`

Comment: @Kartikeya cssTest is the string inside style and it's a js valid property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule.cssText (altho used for different things jQuery seems to implement it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `animate()`, then `.remove()` after the animation. Check out the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8gavv7n2/2/

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $('div').animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function(){
        $(this).remove()
    });
});
```

You'll need to include jQueryUI too.

Comment: That doesnt make to display none instead it still holds the place for the div there even its hide

Comment: Okay... add a function to remove it after the fade - http://jsfiddle.net/8gavv7n2/2/

Comment: Thats cool you can update your answer with this so I can approve it.

Comment: I dont think i need to add jQueryUI are you sure hope it does work with plain jquery without ui

Comment: [Update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/8gavv7n2/5/) without jQuery UI

Comment: Sweet as, even better!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61886/discussion-between-benjamin-and-alex-thomas).

Answer (score 1):

Override it after the transition has finished

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  $('div').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).css("cssText", "display: none !important;");
  })
});
```

```css
div{
    display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello Jquery</div>
```

And the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8gavv7n2/3/